# Best way to build an app-like webpage that fits all displays

Tags: css, html

Basically a calculator app. Terminal / text field up top. 4x4 grid of buttons below it. Everything should scale to fill any screen. I know this is extraordinarily open ended. You can be general in your answers. Use a table? Divs? What kind of display? Fixed? I don't know how to best approach it.

Comment: How are there answers that insist that tables must not be used without knowing whether or not the data being presented is tabular?  We only know that the grid is going to contain buttons, not what actions the buttons represent.

Answer (score 1):

There's no best solution, the simplest is to use `table`s, the most modern to use `display: grid` but won't work on all browsers, you could also try putting whatever you write in a fixed `width` and `height` element and using css3's `transform: scale` to "fit screen", but that also doesn't work in all browsers, you could also do it using 4 `inline-block` with `height: 100%; width: 25%;` elements inside 4 `block` elements with `height: 25%`, or using 16 `inline-block` elements with `width: 25%; height: 25%`, another solution is could define all 16 elements with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` and `width:25%; height:25%` and define the `top` and `left` for each individually. I think for all the mentioned solutions you should also not forget to set `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }`.

Of course you might want to adjust those percentages if you add margins, but set those also in percentages so they look good when you scale.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tables.

You want to look into responsive web design.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

I'd use a grid system.  Check into a few to see what suits what you are doing.  You want your grid to be flexible, so percentage based, rather than pixel based.  That way you won't have to rely on media query break points to change the widths - it will just flex with the viewport width.

eg  (

```
      .onecol    { width: 5.801104972%;  }       
      .twocol    { width: 14.364640883%; }       
      .threecol  { width: 22.928176794%; }       
      .fourcol   { width: 31.491712705%; }       
      .fivecol   { width: 40.055248616%; }      
      .sixcol    { width: 48.618784527%; }       
      .sevencol  { width: 57.182320438000005%; } 
      .eightcol  { width: 65.74585634900001%; }  
      .ninecol   { width: 74.30939226%; }       
      .tencol    { width: 82.87292817100001%; }  
      .elevencol { width: 91.436464082%; }      
      .twelvecol { width: 99.999999993%; }       

      /* layout & column defaults */
      .onecol, .twocol, .threecol, .fourcol, .fivecol, .sixcol, .sevencol, .eightcol, .ninecol, .tencol, .elevencol, .twelvecol {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2.762430939%;
      }

      .first {
        margin-left: 0;
      }

      .last {
        float: right;
      }
```

So your input would be in a twelvecol and then move have buttons into a threecol grid

That said, you will find that for portrait mode on phones and down, you might need to change the layout, so use media queries and alter the css to maybe only show two buttons per row from there.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question, why is `twelvecol` not 100%?

Comment: Good question - its an ie7 thing.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to work with divs but for this kind of grid maybe a table will be easier way, but for sure use precents as a values for width and height, you maybe use colspan and rowspan to fit your table cells in the right way

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your buttons fixed at 4x4, go with a responsive design.

Don't use tables, use Divs.

Don't use a fixed display, or an absolute display. (I guess you could, but why?)

Finally, the answer you're looking for: [Responsive Design](http://responsivedesign.ca/)